# POINT returning nil with activerecord-postgis-adapter on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, postgis, rgeo

I'm using activerecord-postgis-adapter to save (latitude, longitude) values as `POINT`s.  Points are saved using the following syntax: `POINT( lat lng)`.  My model, `Foo`, has an attribute `spot`, where the `POINT` is saved.  When deployed to Heroku, `spot` is always nil after creating a new `Foo`.  However, it works as expected in the following situations:

- Locally with development database (both in production and development environments)
- Locally while connected to production database
- In the rails console inside Heroku

activerecord-postgis-adapter is the same version both locally and on Heroku (2.2.0).  Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be different in the Heroku production environment (that doesn't surface in the console) that might be causing this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you need to provide the correct axis order: `POINT(lng lat)` (think X Y).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually do have that saved correctly, but switched it up in the post.

Comment: Could you try setting the SRID explicitly? Here are some options: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58605/39833